# Append data in a div element from .each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, foreach, each

I am having a html menu and i want to fetch some information and manipulate it for using somewhere else.

but in each loop i am unable to push data to my respective element.

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sahilpopli/9ps59p78/1/)

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
         // create a element container
            navDiv = $("#menu");


            $( "#mainnav .leval1" ).each(function() {
                var parent = $(this).children('a').html();
                var child = $(this).next('.navbox').html();
                var menuBlock = "<li><span> " +parent + "</span> " + child + "</li>";

               navDiv += menuBlock;
                console.log(menuBlock);
            });
```

HTML

```
<p id="print"></p>

<div id="menu"></div>

       <div id="mainnav">
    <div class="leval1"><a href="">lorem2</a></div>
    <div class="navbox">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">lorem2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">lorem2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">lorem2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">lorem2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="leval1"><a href="">lorem2</a></div>
    <div class="navbox">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">lorem2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">lorem2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">lorem2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">lorem2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="leval1"><a href="">lorem2</a></div>
    <div class="navbox">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">lorem2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">lorem2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">lorem2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">lorem2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="leval1"><a href="">lorem2</a></div>
    <div class="navbox">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">lorem2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">lorem2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">lorem2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">lorem2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="leval1"><a href="">lorem2</a></div>
    <div class="navbox">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">lorem2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">lorem2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">lorem2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">lorem2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a spelling issue in `leval1` and `$( "#mainnav .level1" )` so your selector is not returning anything

Comment: Sorry for that but that it is just in case of this demo on my original data value is printing in console

Comment: And you're missing a closing `});` pair.

Comment: @PeterKA since OP is saying s/he is getting the console logging it could be a copy/paste mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use .append() nto string concatenation `+`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var navDiv = $("#menu");

  $("#mainnav .leval1").each(function(i) {
    if (i % 4 == 0) {
      //fourth iterration do something
    }
    var parent = $(this).children('a').html();
    var child = $(this).next('.navbox').html();
    var menuBlock = "<li><span>p: " + parent + "</span> " + child + "</li>";
    $('#print').html(menuBlock);

    //also the + operator won't work with jQuery object you need to append them
    navDiv.append(menuBlock);
    console.log(menuBlock);
  });
  //navDiv.mmenu();
});
```

```css
#print {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#menu {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="print"></p>

<!--Since you are appending `li` elemetns, menu should be a ul-->
<ul id="menu"></ul>

<div id="mainnav">
  <div class="leval1"><a href="">lorem2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbox">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">lorem2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">lorem2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">lorem2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">lorem2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="leval1"><a href="">lorem2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbox">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">lorem2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">lorem2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">lorem2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">lorem2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="leval1"><a href="">lorem2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbox">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">lorem2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">lorem2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">lorem2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">lorem2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="leval1"><a href="">lorem2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbox">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">lorem2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">lorem2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">lorem2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">lorem2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="leval1"><a href="">lorem2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="navbox">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">lorem2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">lorem2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">lorem2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">lorem2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @SahilPopli I've added comments in the areas where I did the corrections

Comment: One more question i have mmenuu to be initialize after this 
how to fire mmenu event after binding this.

 '$('nav#menu').mmenu();'

Comment: @SahilPopli sorry what do you mean by saying only in first loop

Comment: it creates the menu after first rotation of each loop other data is just inserted.

but now it worked on window load

Comment: did you place the code inside the each hadnler or outside

Comment: now i place the code outside ready function and one more thing @Arun

i want to set condition on index value on each loop can it is possible 

like if the each loop is iterating 4th time then do something